# How can mouse click callback and interval function been execute at the same time?

Tags: javascript, event-loop

I was reading this article [How JavaScript Timers Work](https://johnresig.com/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/). And got quite confused as it says `Note that while mouse click handler is executing the first interval callback executes`. While the mouse click handler is executing, how can interval callback executes? Since js is single thread, isn't it so that only one thing can be executing at a time?

Comment: That sentence is wrong, but looking at the diagram https://johnresig.com/files/427px-Timers.png makes what he probably *meant* to say clearer. It *may* be correct to say that the first interval callback is *queued* while the mouse click handler is executing.

Comment: Here is complete syntax from your link `Note that while mouse click handler is executing the first interval callback executes. As with the timer its handler is queued for later execution.` It clearly states that `callback` will be `queued for later execution`

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the next sentence explains pretty well what actually happens:

> As with the timer its handler is queued for later execution.

The whole point of the article seems to be "timeouts/intervals don't fire at the very point you specify, but at the next free point in time after you specified".

Answer (score 0):

Handling of the window methods is not a js-task but a browserspecific task. 
Learn by breaking it:

- What happens if you fire a method that takes 10 seconds every 1
  second?
- What happens if you reset the OS Clock while waiting?

-> All Browser implement their own "window" Object w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp

Basically i say the loop is running in another thread.